# Two javascript arrays, using a key to look up

Tags: javascript, arrays, key-value

I have two data structures (they are much longer, these are just excerpts)

```
var data = [
    {count: 6, zip: "78705"},
    {count: 4, zip: "78754"},
    {count: 33, zip: "78757"}
]

var txcodes = [
    {county: "SWISHER", code:  "437"}, 
    {county: "TARRANT", code:  "439"}, 
    {county: "TAYLOR", code:  "441"}, 
    {county: "TRAVIS", code: "453"}
]
```

I have written code that successfully goes through “data” and takes the zipcode and retrieves the corresponding county (from an external website via HTTP request).  It returns a structure that looks like

```
results = { 
    TRAVIS: 8, 
    TAYLOR: 1 
}
```

(8 and 1 are examples of counters for how many times a zipcode from data occurs…basically a running count).

What I need to do next is use the keys from results to look up what the corresponding code in txcodes is. How do I do this?

```
 var currentCounty = str.result[0].County
```

returns the county from results.

```
console.log(txcodes[i].county + "    " + txcodes[i].code)
```

prints the county & code from txcodes.

I’m a little confused on how to do this. It seems like a relatively simple concept but I can’t seem to get the desired result. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm not sure it's entirely clear what you are asking...

Comment: We're also confused by your question.  Please try to be more specific about your problem.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the keys from `results`?

Comment: It doesn't look like the results you posted have the keys you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

If county names are unique *and* if you are going to be making repeated lookups, you should build a "map" of the codes out of the array:

```
var txcodesByCounty = txcodes.reduce(function(p, c) {
    p[c.county] = c.code;
    return p;
}, {});
```

You can then look up codes directly from this map.

Answer (score 0):

Build a lookup map like this :

```
var lookupMap = {};

for (var i = 0; i < txcodes.length; i++) {
    var element = txcodes[i];
    lookupMap[element.county] = element;
}
```

Then you can simply do this to print the desired output :

```
console.log(lookupMap[currentCounty].county + "    " + lookupMap[currentCounty].code);
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you get back from your HTTP request is a simple object, and you need to access its property names. You can do that easily with `Object.keys`:

```
resultKeys = Object.keys(result);
```

This will give you an array of the object properties:

```
[ "TRAVIS", "TAYLOR" ]
```

You can easily iterate over this array now, and inside you ask your result object for its value:

```
for (var i = 0; i < resultKeys.length; i++) {
    console.log(resultkeys[i] + ": " + result[resultkeys[i]]);
}
```

Using this technique, you can use for example [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) libary to easily filter for your desired data:

```
for (var i = 0; i < resultKeys.length; i++) {
    console.log(_.filter(txcodes , function(key){ return txcodes.county== resultkeys[i]; }));
}
```

Comment: this does not help the OP find the specific code for a given key.

Comment: if you're recommending underscore then you should read the underscore manual! - in this case `_.findWhere(txcodes, { county: currentCounty })` would be the appropriate method.

Answer (score 0):

If the county in your result is only available as a *key*, you'll need to `for..in`, `Object.keys` or `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` to access them.

After, access the details via a map as others have suggested

```
var county, found = [];
for (county in results)
    found.push(map[county]);
```